# React-Native running on Android device from AppleOS, no udev directory

Tags: macos, react-native

The instructions for how to run a react-native project on an android device is located at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

After determining your USB device, the instructions state to do the following command:

```
echo SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" | 
sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-usb.rules
```

The problem is that there is not a `/etc/udev` directory on my Mac. So obviously this fails.

[Apparently MacOS doesn't support udev.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46951/is-there-a-mac-equivalent-for-udev-folder-on-linux)

So how do I get this to work? If I ignore the udev part and use the command `react-native run-android` then it wants to run on an emulator. I experimented with `--variant` and just adding the values from `adb devices`, but no success.

--edit--

I should note that `adb devices` works fine, so does `lsusb`. The phone prompted to trust the computer, so I know that debugging is setup correctly. Just trying to figure out how to tell `react-native` to launch the app on the device (instead of an emulator).

Comment: Have you enabled 'developer options' and 'usb debugging' in your Android device?

Comment: Yep, all enabled. I have successfully debugged via a seperate system (running windows).

Comment: For mac, no need of setting '/etc/udev', strange it didn't work for you.